# Converting a bunch of nested recursive functions to iterative funcs

Tags: recursion, iteration

I have read that it is in principle possible to convert a recursive function to an iterative function. I have some bunch of functions calling each other. I constructed the structure of the code looking at my flowchart and it was kind of obvious to do it by recursive style. It runs good for small size problems but gives segmentation fault for bigger scale. So I am trying to switch to iterative style but I cannot imagine a way to do it technically since the branching structure confuses me. Can someone give me a clue to handle it? The code is something like that in python:

```
def main_function(parameters):
    if condition0:
       ....
       if condition1:
           ....
           if condition2:
               ....
               return function1(parameters)
           else:
               ....
               return function2(parameters)
       else:
           return function1(parameters)
    else:
       return function2(parameters)
#############################################
def function1(parameters):
    if condition3:
       ...
       return function3(parameters)   ### yet another function.. so messed up? :-(((
    else:
       return main_function(parameters)
##############################################
def function2(parameters):
    if condition4:
       ...
       return main_function(parameters)
    else:
       return function1(parameters)
###############################################
def function3(parameters):
   if condition5
      if condition6:
         ...
         return function3(parameters)
      else:
         ...
         return main_function(parameters)
   else:
      return RESULTS   # The only way out!
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I like to think of it as "every recursive function can be written as a stack based one". Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since every `return` statement that you've shown is essentially a `return some_other_function()`, it seems that a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) would be a natural way to model this. There would be a state corresponding to each function, and the `return` statements would become state transitions.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i made a quick research on fsm but i am not a professional programmer, is it possible to do it with like if's and while's or similar "simple" stuff??

Answer (score 0):

Since every recursive call is initiated in `return` statements. You don't need to hold up the old stack. For example, when `function1()` calls `return function3()`, `function1` stack can be removed. This way you won't get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

You can achieve this by returning the successive function to call with parameters, instead of calling recursively.

```
def main_function(parameters):
if condition0:
   if condition1:
       if condition2:
           return function1, parameters # return function to call next with arguments
       else:
           ....
           return function2, parameters
   else:
       return function1, parameters
else:
   return function2, parameters
```

You should change the other functions to a similar way. Now you can call the `main_function()` as follows:

```
next_function, next_fun_param = main_function(parameters)
while hasattr(next_function, '__call__')
    next_function, next_fun_param = next_function(next_fun_param)
# got the RESULT
```

Comment: ok this seems like it is going to work... thank you very much